# Is there any way to automatically have the API Keys in Azure API Management also be used with function level authentication for Functions?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-api-management

If I expose an Azure Function with function level authentication through Azure API Management (APIM) then I want the same API Key from APIM to be used in the Function. Is there any way to achieve this though configuration or is scripting required?

Answer (score 0):

At APIM side you're talking about subscription key, right? If so you could configure API at APIM side to not require subscription key at all, i.e. make it anonymously callable, and rely on Function to do the authentication.

Alternatively you could configure API to receive subscription key in "code" query param and "x-functions-key" header, and create a subscription with key matching Function key.